# Is it legal to track a scammer's IP address?

Tags: internet, privacy, fraud, online, spam

One of my contacts has messaged me asking for help about a scam. He was saying that one same person keeps harassing him with scam messages threatening to put some videos of him online if he doesn't pay them a certain amount of money.

So I was thinking of just somehow fooling the scammer to click on a link such as grabify.link so that my contact could get their IP address (hoping they are not using a VPN) and go to the police with it, is this actually a legal thing to do?

Comment: Why doesn’t he just block the scammer?

Comment: @DaleM because videos of him will be put online, if the scammer is not bluffing?

Comment: No one will watch or care about the videos.

Comment: You should tell your jurisdiction. That said, your contact shold directly go to the police because A) they have way more means at their disposal and B) evidence collected by them will be more difficult to invalidate than any evidence provided by you.

Comment: @Brandin “Publish and be damned” I reckon!

Comment: @immibis think the scammer is probably bluffing (as they often do) but we never know...

Comment: @SJuan76 That's what I ended up telling him in the end, to just go see the police about the issue.